# Trigger worksheet change routine if a specific value is entered into a specific column

Tags: excel, vba

Basic premise is that I'm trying to set up error handling such that if a person puts a "Y" into the last column of a table (this is dynamic) but they haven't filled out all the other cells in the row, they get an error message and the "Y" is deleted. Here is the code I have on the specific sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myrange As Range
Dim columnnumber As Integer
Dim columnletter As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim targetcolumn As Range

columnnumber = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
columnletter = Split(Cells(1, columnnumber).Address, "$")(1)
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set targetcolumn = Columns(columnnumber)

'Determine if change was made to last column of table
If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Columns(columnnumber))) Is Nothing Then
    'Determine if "Y" is added to last column without having filled all fields
    For i = 1 To lastrow
      If Cells(i, columnnumber).Value = "Y" And IsEmpty(Range((Cells(i, 1)), (Cells(i, columnnumber - 1)))) = True Then
        Cells(i, columnnumber).ClearContents
        MsgBox ("Make sure to fill all fields before copying to Master Sheet.")
      End If
    Next i
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range(Columns(columnnumber))` looks off. What's the error message and on what line?

Comment: Probably should add `Application.EnableEvents = False` to turn off events while you make changes to the sheet, and then re-enable at the end with `= True`.

Comment: In `Worksheet_Change` (or any code in a sheet module) you can/should use `Me` to refer to the sheet itself.

Comment: @bigben The error is "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: Should be `If Not Intersect(Target, targetcolumn) Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: Why do you need iterating through all the range? Why don't you check only the `Target` cell? After solving of intersection conditions, which is certainly wrong...

Comment: @bigben thank you! I fixed the If Not Intersect like you suggested and it works! BUT, I do have a question now about the application.enableevents = False. I've run the workbook and it's not picking up that I'm changing that column + leaving one field blank. Can you let me know where I should be putting this code?

Comment: @faneduru There's a potential chance that someone might go back and change a previous row within the column. Trying to dummy proof this as hard as possible.

Comment: @timwilliams Do you mean like instead of Worksheets("Sheet 1").whatever, I'd do Me.whatever?

Comment: Yes, that’s it.

Comment: Is your data contiguous i.e. no empty rows or columns? Is the first cell `A1`? If so, why don't you use `lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`. Also, you could do `Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Me.Range("A1").CurrentRegion` to create a reference to the 'table range'. Also, you could do `... And Application.CountBlank(Me.Range(Me.Cells(i, 1), Me.Cells(i, columnnumber - 1))) > 0 Then`. Rather do it in two `If` statements. To 'shorten' the loop, you could use the `Find` method or the `AutoFilter` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Trigger When Value in Column Changes (Worksheet Change Event)

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckFields(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const ProcName As String = "CheckFields"
    Const Criteria As String = "Y"
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Target.Worksheet.UsedRange
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    Dim lcrg As Range: Set lcrg = rg.Columns(cCount)
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(lcrg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim fcrg As Range: Set fcrg = rg.Columns(1).Resize(, cCount - 1)
    
    Dim iCell As Range
    Dim foundBlanks As Boolean
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    For Each iCell In irg.Cells '*** maybe lcrg.Cells
        If CStr(iCell.Value) = Criteria Then
        ' If you want to allow lower case 'y', use (instead):
        'If StrComp(CStr(iCell.Value), Criteria, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            If Application.CountBlank(Intersect(fcrg, iCell.EntireRow)) > 0 Then
                iCell.ClearContents
                If Not foundBlanks Then
                    foundBlanks = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next iCell
    
SafeExit:
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If foundBlanks Then
        MsgBox "Make sure to fill all fields before copying to Master Sheet."
    End If

    Exit Sub

ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
        & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
        & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit

End Sub
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    CheckFields Target
End Sub
```